# C++ AWSCredentials : undefined reference to `Aws::Free(void*)'

Tags: c++, amazon-web-services

I am learning `C++` by reading Stroustrup's book and I am practicing on some work related code.

I need to write some small code for calling the `Amazon Simple Systems Manager` (which if I were to do it python would take about 5 min, but this is for learning).

The first thing I need to do is create a [credentials](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/cpp/api/0.12.9/d4/d27/class_aws_1_1_auth_1_1_a_w_s_credentials.html#a8aca53af9eec8a118c448790e28a4f2d) object with the Access and Secret keys.  This is proving harder than I thought!

```
#include <aws/core/Aws.h>
#include <aws/core/auth/AWSCredentialsProvider.h>
...
char const* AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = "aaaaaaa";
char const* AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = "bbbbb";

Aws::Auth::AWSCredentials creds(AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY);
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
In function `Aws::Allocator<char>::deallocate(char*, unsigned long)':
main.cpp: undefined reference to `Aws::Free(void*)'
```

Best I can figure is this is a problem with how the [Aws::String](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/cpp/api/0.12.9/de/dca/namespace_aws.html#ac45eb95643c91062d4d82a28d453aae7) is supposed to work?

According to the docs it's `typedef std::basic_string< char, std::char_traits< char >, Aws::Allocator< char > >`

I looked at `basic_string` and that's just the standard library string, beyond that I am lost.

Comment: Maybe instead of down voting, make an attempt to explain what you don't like? Did not ask the question correctly? Did I not google enough before asking?

Comment: Undefined reference means linker cannot find this function, which usually means you did not specify necessary libs for linking. Check docs which libs are required.

Comment: @Sam. I am sorry that someone downvoted your question. I just upvoted it. I have a lot of experience with the AWS C++ SDK. It will take some time to learn the "Amazon Coding Style" for the SDK. Post new questions with your source code and I will try to jump in with help when I am available.

Comment: @JohnHanley Many thanks for your help! This community can be tough sometimes.  At times it is warranted, but at not always.

Comment: Your reputation is high enough that this should not happen. I do know how that feels. I even get downvoted when my answer was selected as the best answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the headers that I include for simple programs to test credentials using the Amazon C++ SDK:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <aws/core/Aws.h>
#include <aws/core/utils/memory/stl/AWSString.h>
#include <aws/core/utils/logging/DefaultLogSystem.h>
#include <aws/core/utils/logging/AWSLogging.h>
#include <aws/core/auth/AWSCredentialsProvider.h>
#include <aws/core/auth/AWSCredentialsProviderChain.h>
```

In your linker include the aws-cpp-sdk-core.lib library.

Note: I am using Visual Studio to build my projects.

Comment: Thanks! I am using the Linux `g++ --std=c++11` from the command line, but this is still very helpful!